# how to launch 2 activities in response to single nfc tap

Tags: android, ndef

I'm trying to launch several app on after one tap, how do i do this?
Is there just one mime-type per NDEF message in android?

for example can my NDEF message contain 2 records each contains specific mime-type:

com.firstapp
com.seconapp

and then can i filter intents in activities in order to launch both?

Answer (score 0):

How do you imagine "start two activities"? Android allows only one to be running.
If you need you can add intent filters to two of your apps for the same intent and let user choose one.
Or you can just run your own service and code everything what you want (and is technicaly possible).

Answer (score 0):

One NDEF message can contain multiple record.

The first byte of the NDEF containe MB and ME.

MB set to 1 : It's the first record of the current NDEF exchange

ME set to 1 : It's the last record of the current NDEF exchange

I'm looking for a good picture of a multiple record exchange chronogram. I'll update this post if I found it.

Edit : [Nokia dev explanation](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Understanding_NFC_Data_Exchange_Format_%28NDEF%29_messages)